# Pandas - chunk read_csv with overlap between chunks

Tags: python, pandas, csv

**Problem statement**

How to chunk read a csv file using pandas which has an overlap between chunks?

For an example, imagine the list `indexes` represents the index of some dataframe I wish to read in.

```
indexes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

read_csv(filename, chunksize=None):

```
indexes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  # read in all indexes at once
```

read_csv(filename, chunksize=5):

```
indexes = [[0,1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9]]  # iteratively read in mutually exclusive index sets
```

read_csv(filename, chunksize=5, **overlap=2**):

```
indexes = [[0,1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6,7], [6,7,8,9]]  # iteratively read in indexes sets with overlap size 2
```

**Working solution**

I have a hack solution using *skiprows* and *nrows*, but it gets progressively slower as it reads the csv file.

```
indexes = [*range(10)]
chunksize = 5
overlap_count = 2
row_count = len(indexes)  # this I can work out before reading the whole file in rather cheaply

chunked_indexes = [(i, i + chunksize) for i in range(0, row_count, chunksize - overlap_count)]  # final chunk here may be janky, assume it works for now (it's more about the logic)
for chunk in chunked_indexes:
    skiprows = [*range(chunk[0], chunk[1])]
    pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=skiprows, nrows=chunksize)
```

Does anyone have any insights or improved solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass a number to `skiprow` instead of the list, try:

```
for i in list(range(0, row_count-overlap_count, chunksize - overlap_count)):
    print (pd.read_csv('test.csv', 
                       skiprows=i+1, #here it is +1 because the first row was header 
                       nrows=chunksize, 
                       index_col=0, # this was how I save my csv
                       header=None) # you may need to read header before
             .index)
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64', name=0)
Int64Index([3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype='int64', name=0)
Int64Index([6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64', name=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, though unfortunately passing skiprows as an integer doesn't solve the issue of reading the file becoming progressively slower for higher iterations. Here's some testing results:
iteration #0, time: 0.0039s
iteration #100, time: 0.0208s
iteration #200, time: 0.0403s
iteration #300, time: 0.0597s

Comment: @Andy interesting! out of curiosity, when using the parameter chunksize of read_csv, there is no difference in timing, right?

Comment: Turns out there is a difference! read_csv with parameter chunksize has ~ constant time between iterations

Comment: @Andy yeah it is what I tried to say, excuse my English :) have you tried to use the parameter `engine='c'`,the doc says it is faster. It will not change the difference between iteration, but maybe overall faster